# Can record processor be spring singleton bean?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka to implement the topology to convert lower-case to upper-case like this:

```
        @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStreamPromoToUppercase(StreamsBuilder builder) {

        KStream<String, String> sourceStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        // A new processor object is created here per record 
        sourceStream.process(() -> new CapitalCaseProcessor());
        ...
    }
```

The processor is **not a spring singleton bean** and is declared as follows:

```
public class CapitalCaseProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        context.headers().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

The above processor is a stateful and holds the state of processor context.

Now, what would happen if we convert the stateful `CapitalCaseProcessor` to a **spring singleton bean** ?

```
@Component
public class CapitalCaseProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {
    
    //Is the ProcessorContext going to have thread safety issue now?
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        context.headers().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

and try to inject it in the main topology as spring bean:

```
@Configuration
public class UppercaseTopologyProcessor {
       @Autowired CapitalCaseProcessor capitalCaseProcessor;
        @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStreamPromoToUppercase(StreamsBuilder builder) {

        KStream<String, String> sourceStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        // A singleton spring bean processor is now used for all the records 
        sourceStream.process(() -> capitalCaseProcessor);
        ...
    }
```

Is it going to cause thread safety issue with the CapitalCaseProcessor now as it contains `processorContext` as a state?

Or is it better to declare it as a prototype bean like this as this?

```
@Configuration
public class UppercaseTopologyProcessor {
           
     @Lookup
     public CapitalCaseProcessor getCapitalCaseProcessor() {return null;}
        
     @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStreamPromoToUppercase(StreamsBuilder builder) {

        KStream<String, String> sourceStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        // A singleton spring bean processor is now used for all the records 
        sourceStream.process(() -> getCapitalCaseProcessor());
        ...
    }
```

Update: I essentially would like to know two things:

1. Should the processor instance be associated per stream record like AKKA actor model where actors are stateful and works per request or it can be a singleton object?
2. Is ProcessorContext thread safe?

Comment: Making it a prototype bean will make no difference since the `@Autowired` is only applied once during startup. I don't know Kafka Streams internals well enough to know whether the context is thread-safe (but I would hope so).

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks!, I have updated my question to provide more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran a test and, the processor context is NOT thread-safe, what makes the stream thread-safe is you use a `ProcessorSupplier` (in your first example) to create a new processor instance for each record.

You must certainly not replace this with a Spring singleton.

Here is my test, using the `MessagingTransformer` provided by Spring for Apache Kafka:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class So66200448Application {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So66200448Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66200448Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    KStream<String, String> stream(StreamsBuilder sb) {
        KStream<String, String> stream = sb.stream("so66200448");

        stream.transform(() ->  new MessagingTransformer(msg -> {
            log.info(msg.toString());
            log.info(new String(msg.getHeaders().get("foo", byte[].class)));
            return msg;
        }, new MessagingMessageConverter()) {

            @Override
            public KeyValue transform(Object key, Object value) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return super.transform(key, value);
            }

        })
            .to("so66200448out");
        return stream;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66200448").partitions(2).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66200448out").partitions(2).replicas(1).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            Headers headers = new RecordHeaders();
            headers.add(new RecordHeader("foo", "bar".getBytes()));
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("so66200448", 0, null, "foo", headers);
            template.send(record);
            headers.remove("foo");
            headers.add(new RecordHeader("foo", "baz".getBytes()));
            record = new ProducerRecord<>("so66200448", 1, null, "bar", headers);
            template.send(record);
        };
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66200448out", topics = "so66200448out")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.streams.application-id=so66200448
spring.kafka.streams.properties.num.stream.threads=2
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

> 2021-02-16 15:57:34.322  INFO 17133 --- [-StreamThread-1] com.example.demo.So66200448Application   : bar

> 2021-02-16 15:57:34.322  INFO 17133 --- [-StreamThread-2] com.example.demo.So66200448Application   : baz

Changing the supplier to return the same instance each time, definitely breaks it.

```java
@Bean
KStream<String, String> stream(StreamsBuilder sb) {
    KStream<String, String> stream = sb.stream("so66200448");
    MessagingTransformer transformer = new MessagingTransformer(msg -> {
        log.info(msg.toString());
        log.info(new String(msg.getHeaders().get("foo", byte[].class)));
        return msg;
    }, new MessagingMessageConverter()) {

        @Override
        public KeyValue transform(Object key, Object value) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return super.transform(key, value);
        }

    };
    stream.transform(() ->  transformer)
        .to("so66200448out");
    return stream;
}
```

> 2021-02-16 15:54:28.975  INFO 16406 --- [-StreamThread-1] com.example.demo.So66200448Application   : baz

> 2021-02-16 15:54:28.975  INFO 16406 --- [-StreamThread-2] com.example.demo.So66200448Application   : baz

So, streams relies on getting a new instance each time for thread-safety.

Comment: You could, of course, register it as a prototype bean and get a new instance from the application context each time the supplier is called `() -> context.getBean("myProcessor", Processor.class)`. But that would only add value if you need to perform some Spring initialization on it.

Comment: I think I asked similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76745168/kafkastream-passing-bean-as-transformer/, it means it's not possible to provide transformer as Bean? I want it as bean to inject multiple components that i need inside ... instead of manually creating instances and  passing them in constructor.

Comment: You can define it as a prototype bean (instead of singleton), but your transformer supplier will need to get it from the application context each time.