# KafkaStream passing Bean as Transformer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I am using `KafkaStreams`  in springboot project.

KafkaStreamFlow definition  class:

```
@Component
public class KafkaStreamFlow {
   @PostConstruct    
   public void flow() {

       //...

       KStream<String, Data> st1 = st0
                    .transform(() -> new CustomTransformer(),...);

   }
}
```

Is it possible, instead of passing new instance of `Transformer`, to pass a `Bean`?

As I understand, topology will create **new Instance** of Transformer for each kafkastream's **task**.

so if I pass to transform method

```
.transform(() -> beanCustomTransformer(),...);
```

will it lead to issues?

Answer (score 0):

You should let your topology do the processor/transformer creation for you. By default spring beans are singleton, however Kafka Streams makes no such guarantee on your transformer creation.

In my experience it's usually best to create factories/providers and let topology handle this for you. If you'd like to still use spring consider providing your beans in suppliers, like `Supplier<MyBean>` that way the topology can do it's thing, and you can still do any spring configuration you need in configuration classes or via annotations.

So your configuration class would be like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<CustomTransformer> myBeanSupplier() {
        return () -> new CustomTransformer();
    }
}
```

and then to inject it into your TopologyCreator:

```
@Component
class MyTopology {
    private Supplier<CustomTransformer> supplier;
    
    // constructor injection for supplier

     @PostConstruct    
   public void flow() {

       //...

       KStream<String, Data> st1 = st0
                    .transform(supplier,...);

   }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid  that just providing bean as i did above will cause issue. Can you please provide code example Supplier<MyBean> , as it does not seems right. where is this Supplier comes from?

Comment: You can define it as a prototype bean (instead of singleton), but your transformer supplier will need to get it from the application context each time.

Comment: sounds good, nothing wrong of doing context.getBean() right?

Comment: Or you can use the prototype scope, however be aware, that this is only activated when the context makes the request for a new bean. So as you mentioned, context.getBean() must be called. The supplier approach is roughly equivalent to that.